# Programmatically delete emails and SMSs on a Window Mobile device

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm looking for a code snippet that can delete all emails and text messages on a Windows Mobile device. Preferably the code would delete items in the Sent and Draft folders as well as the Inbox.

My platform is Windows Mobile (5.0 SDK) and .net 2.0 compact framework (C# / VB.NET)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Microsoft has **not** made this easy for managed developers.  Why the WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook class wrappers don't provide this functionality one can only guess.  What you have to do is write your own COM interop object to MAPI. Sorry, I don't have one to give you as a sample, but I can at least give you pointers to the methods you'll be interested in:

- [IMAPI::GetMsgStoresTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859847.aspx)
- [IMAPISession::OpenMessageStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859878.aspx)
- [IMsgStore::OpenEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms860167.aspx)
- [IMAPIFolder::DeleteMessages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859723.aspx)

[InTheHand has a wrapper](http://inthehand.com/content/Mobile.aspx) that has additional methods for POOM, but I've never used it and I don't know if it has anything that does what you need.  Might be worth a look, though, before embarking on rolling this yourself.